# No adapter for handler exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a web application using spring mvc framework. I want to to both annotation and beanName based url mappings.

I've the following configurations in my context file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"></bean>
```

My annotation based controllers are working fine but beanNamed based url mapping are throwing the exception "No adapter for handler".

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 80):

By default the spring mvc defines 3 different request handler adapters, they are

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
```

So you need not have to define them in your context file, but if you define at least one handler adapter in your context files, spring will not create the default adapters.

In your configuraion you are using `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, according to [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) spring documentation this will cause the context to define both `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. Since we are creating the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` in our context definition spring will not create the other two handlerAdapters. That is why you are getting the said exception.

The beanNameUrlMapping needs the handlerAdapter `SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter`.

To resolve this exception you can simply create a new bean of type "SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" in your context.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter">
</bean>
```

Comment: this is simple an direct answer, great explanation :)

Comment: This was not easy to find. But i did eventually. Excellent explanation. I was adding annotation support and didn't want to migrate all the controllers at the same time.

Comment: It worked fine for me by adding SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter. Thanks!

Comment: _but if you define at least one handler adapter in your context files, spring will not create the default adapters_...  Soo important...  Found one of them defined in one of many spring configs, so the others _did not_ get defined.  Painful investigation, thanks for the info!

Comment: In my case adding `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` solved the problem, but the key is that I had to put it in the servlet config **AFTER** the `mvc:annotation-driven` configuration

Comment: Just to say that `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is now deprecated and can be replaced with `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me when I was trying to integrate spring MVC 2.5 with spring web flow. For webflow I have given FlowHandlerdAdapter in the configuration file but none for MVC. Thereby as said above we need to define a BEAN of type simplecontrollerhandleradapter in this case which will solve the problem.