# How to enable Spring 3.0 MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter with @ResponseBody AND pre-Spring-3.0 Controller SimpleUrlHandlerMapping together?

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

As the title suggests, I'm trying and failing to get the following combination working in Spring 3.0:

- pre-Spring-3.0 controllers mapped with SimpleUrlHandlerMapping, and,
- a Spring-3.0 @Controller using MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter and @ResponseBody to return JSON.

All the pieces work - except when put together!

In more detail, I have an existing Spring web-app which includes many pre-Spring-3.0 controllers.  These implement Controller and are mapped explicitly with a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping bean.  (So one solution is to change them all to @Controller style).  The same web-app (DispatcherServlet) also supports several newer controllers annotated with @Controller.

My bean config includes the following, and all is good:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/path/name.ext">mySpring25Controller</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
</bean>
```

Now I'm adding, to a new controller annotated with @Controller and @RequestMapping, use of MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter so that with @ResponseBody some of my methods can return JSON via Jackson - to Ajax calls.  Again all is good:

```
<!-- to generate JSON responses using Jackson (without using <mvc:annotation-driven/>) -->  
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
        <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is that now my explicit mappings defined in the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping bean are no longer working:

```
[http-8081-Processor25] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/mayapp].[springapp]  - Servlet.service() for servlet springapp threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.mycom.controller.mySpring25Controller ...]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatcherServlet.java:985)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:773)
```

These mappings still appear in my log at start-up (SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Mapped URL path ... etc) - but evidently are now broken somehow.

```
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Mapped URL path [/path/name.ext] onto handler [com.mycom.controller.mySpring25Controller ....]
```

I started with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` which had the same problem.  I've tried re-ordering without success, including order properties.  And I've also not found an explanation in the Spring docs.  It seems there is some interaction in the Spring auto-magic which I haven't got to the bottom of.

Interesting problem anyone?  Insight gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post and ye shall find (delayed by 8 hours for lack of reputation)!

As per post [No adapter for handler exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896013/no-adapter-for-handler-exception) the answer appears to be that the explicit AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter definition blows away the implicit SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter which was previously satisfying the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mappings.

So add it explicitly:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter">
</bean>
```

And we're good, though at the same time you might also need to introduce also an explicit replacement for the implicit HttpRequestHandlerAdapter also blown away:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter">
</bean>
```